# Java: newbie "javac: invalid flag" compile error

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile a Java 1.6 program. The following compiles without error:

```
# javac -cp /path/to/ojdbc6.jar:. MyJavaProgram.java
```

But adding a flag causes this error:

```
# javac -cp /path/to/ojdbc6.jar:. -Doracle.jdbc.SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary=true MyJavaProgram.java -help
javac: invalid flag: -Doracle.jdbc.SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary=true
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Is the flag not supported? I added the `-help` but it didn't give any more info (did I add it in the right place above?).

Comment: You *only* set things at runtime, not compile time.

Comment: ahhh, got it. But what if the java program is called by a client or servlett?

Comment: They need to be set at runtime by either the browser, command line or container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The options must come before the source files (as indicated in your question): remove the `-help`.</strike>

`-D` option specify properties and are passed to the JVM (`java`) and are not compile time flags. From `java -help`:

```
-D<name>=<value>
       set a system property
```

To view the list of available compiler options execute:

> javac -help

Comment: so: # javac -cp /path/to/ojdbc6.jar:. -Doracle.jdbc.SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary=true MyJavaProgram.java